# In python numpy least squares, why a singular normal matrix does NOT raise LinAlgError?

Tags: python, exception, numpy, least-squares, singular

Solving A.X = B by least squares. Given this :

```
import numpy as np
A=[[1,0],[0,0]]
B=[1,0]
X=np.linalg.lstsq(A, B)     # X = 1/(At.A) * (At.B)
print X[0]  # [ 1.  0.]
```

At.A is A, and det(A)=0 --> singular.
So there is an infinity of solutions; [1,0] is one.

Why lstsq doesn't raise np.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError ? The doc says "If computation does not converge.". Is not that the case ?

Does anyone have a simple example where this exception is raised with lstsq ?

Comment: `lstsq` is _designed_ to give you a response even if the system of equations is undetermined...  You may want to look also at `X[3]`, that lists the _singular values_ of the coefficients matrix.